# shrinkwrap animation vacuum distortion

Tags: animation, materials, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to create a shrinkwrap animation where I have a bag of candy and it gets vacuumed around frame 140 out of 200. Everything is working fine, but once the "bag" gets sucked in, it keeps moving and doing these weird wavy effects on the cloth material. I'm assuming that this is being caused by the pressure going from 0 to -150 from frame 140 to 200 in a gradual way, so it's not immediately -150 and it keeps deforming the cloth. I would like to have this vacuumed material still after the suction is complete like it would behave in reality. I've tried adjusting the animation so the shrink wrap would only affect from frame 140 to 160, but after 160 it starts doing some weird stuff instead of staying still. is there any way to have the cloth stay still after the vacuum is done? I would just want it to stay still from frame 160 to 200, but I don't know how to do it. thanks in advance!! here are some images to explain my problem (sorry for the bad quality)

This is the bag before shrinkwrap

[image]

This is in frame 145, the vacuum shape I want to keep

[image]

This is frame 200. It keeps moving and doing this weird vibration effect where the cloth doesn't stop moving.

[image]

Comment: maybe you could stop the simulation at the frame you want (Cache panel)?

Comment: I tried that before, but the cloth starts doing something weird, like inflating again but in these strange bubble shapes within the cloth. So if I bake the shrinkwrap from 140fr to 160fr, right after 160fr the cloth would start doing that...  Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Cloth simulations this precise will always do strange things, unless you use crazy precision in the simulation and that is also no guarantee. Easiest solution (provided the cache panel one isn't working for you) is to copy your object on the frame you like and apply the (cloth) modifier. Then hide the simulation at that frame and start showing the duplicat.

Comment: Thank you so much for both replies, at the end I decided to delete the cloth object and start the simulation from scratch. Then I tried the cache panel option and this time it worked just fine!! I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before but now it's fixed, so thank you very much for the help and ideas!!

Comment: maybe you could answer in detail in the Your Answer field? It may help people trying to achieve the same thing